# Cannot invoke "java.util.Map.getOrDefault(Object, Object)" because null

Tags: java, dictionary, null, double

I'm having trouble accessing the values from a dictionary. I'm using

```java
double storedDistances = dictionary.getOrDefault(lnglat, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)
```

which returns positive infinity if no match is found in the dictionary. I think the error is coming from the dictionary value returning `null`, how can I write a catch to stop null values being carried forward? the specific error is

```
Cannot invoke "java.util.Map.getOrDefault(Object, Object)" because "Planner.dictionary" is null.
```

Help would be appreciated.

I was expecting a double value to  be returned to later compare with another double value. But for unassigned dictionary entries null is being returned which cannot be assigned to the double value.

Comment: From the [javascript tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*[JavaScript] is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities. ...*"

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs (`https://ericlippert.com/`)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: "*I think the error is coming from the dictionary value returning null,..*" - I am not sure I understand you right. But I think that `dictionary` itself is `null`. --- "*... how can I write a catch to stop null values being carried forward?*" - Do not catch `NullPointerException`s. Find out why the value is `null` and fix it. --- For a more thorough analysis, we need a [MRE]. Please [edit] the post and add a [MRE].

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/6395627)

Comment: @Slaw the fact that it only a "possible duplicate" indicates that the post is missing (debug) information :)

Comment: @Turing85 That's why I didn't dupe-hammer :) Though to be fair, the error message in the question is definitely saying that `dictionary` is `null`, and the OP explains they want to fix that error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

```
Cannot invoke "java.util.Map.getOrDefault(Object, Object)" because "Planner.dictionary" is null.
```

Java is complaining that the *dictionary* is `null`, not that `null` is being returned. The Java Virtual Machine throws `NullPointerException`s any time a method is invoked on `null`. That is what is happening in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> I think the error is coming from the dictionary value returning null

Correct (probably ... modulo your confusing terminology).  It is happening because `dictionary` variable has the value `null`.

(The variable isn't "returning" anything.  But if you are trying to say that the `getOrDefault` **call** is returning `null`, that is definitely incorrect!)

> how can I write a catch to stop null values being carried forward?

**You shouldn't do that!!**

Instead, you should find whatever is causing `dictionary` to be `null` in the first place ... and fix that.

And if `dictionary` being `null` is something that you expect to happen (i.e. it is a "normal" occurrence), then you should test the variable before you use it; e.g.

```
double storedDistances;
if (dictionary != null) {
    storedDistances = dictionary.getOrDefault(lnglat, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
} else {
    storedDistances = // some other value
}
```

<sup>(Actually, that's not the best approach either, a better idea would be to initialize `dictionary` to an empty map instead of `null`.  Then you won't need special case code to deal with a null dictionary.  But I'm getting off-track.)</sup>

Catching an unexpected NPE is papering over the cracks.  You need to repair what is causing the cracks to happen so that the wall doesn't fall on your head while you are sleeping.

---

We can't tell you why `dictionary` is `null` or whether it is "normal" because your question doesn't include enough context.